# Can I use Interfaces to hide fields in POCOs so Entity Framework Core does not try to find matching columns in a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project in Entity Framework Core which uses POCOs to connect to a database. However, these POCOs cannot convey intent, which is necessary because of a role-based permission system. I need some way to convey roles alongside my POCO.

However, some of the requirements of the project make it difficult to use subclasses with additional fields to do this. Thus, I have been using interfaces and partial classes, as under normal circumstances, I can use an interface to control which parts of the class are being recognized.

For example, in following code I have a guest entity, with the role of who is editing the entity. Only the fields Id, Name, and Confirmed exist as columns within the database. Under most circumstances, I can cast to an IGuest to remove the "MyRole" field.

```
public partial class Guest : IGuest 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
}

public partial class Guest : IRole
{
     public string MyRole { get; set; }
}

public interface IGuest
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     bool Confirmed { get; set; }
}

public interface IRole
{
     public string MyRole { get; set; }
}
```

However, if I try to create a `DbSet` of guests, it attempts to find a matching column for `MyRole`. I tried changing the following sets of code

```
public virtual DbSet<Guest> Guest { get; set; } = null!;
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Guest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });
```

into the following:

```
public virtual DbSet<IGuest> Guest { get; set; } = null!;
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IGuest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });
```

This results in an error

> ArgumentException: The specified type '...IGuest' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.

Is it possible to use an interface as part of a `DbSet` / entity to hide the `MyRole` field (and any others not in the `IGuest` interface) from Entity Framework so that it does not attempt to map it to a column?

Comment: That's what the `[NotMapped]` attribute is for, no? But why are you messing with your DB entities? Leave them alone/let them carry on representing the DB (only) and use an auto mapper to convert them to viewmodels/DTOs that support the needs of your business logic

Comment: Sadly, I am not the one in charge of the project, and the one in charge insists that we use this method. Additionally, they do not want to use attribute tags. They say it is so that they can easily switch out parts of the project.

Comment: Fluent has `Ignore()`, though it sounds to me like the one in charge needs to resolve the rod they've created for their own(your?) back..

Comment: I talked to them, they're willing to use Ignore() in the FluentAPI. Thanks!

Comment: The proper way to be able to switch out parts of the project, which I'm assuming they maybe mean the DB implementation or service layer, is to not mix the presentation of your data with the data model. By using DTOs/ViewModels like @CaiusJard said.